# ¿Qué función tiene el siguiente fragmento de código?

Tags: java

```
public int compareTo(Object a) {
        int estado=MENOR;

        //Hacemos un casting de objetos para usar el metodo get
        Serie ref=(Serie)a;
        if (numeroTemporadas>ref.getnumeroTemporadas()){
            estado=MAYOR;
        }else if(numeroTemporadas==ref.getnumeroTemporadas()){
            estado=IGUAL;
        }

        return estado;
    }
```

Comment: Lo mismo te viene bien leer esto: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-

Answer (score 2):

Sin duda es el metodo `compareTo(Object)` de la interfaz `Comparable`, quiere decir que la clase `Serie` esta dada como:

```
public class Serie implements Comparable {
  //...
  @Override
  public int compareTo( Object O ) {
    return 0;
  }
  //...
}
```

La función del código que proporcionas sobre-escribiendo el método `compareTo()` sirve básicamente para ordenar los objetos `Serie` de ***menor a mayor***, según el numero que lleve consigo la variable `estado`, que a su vez depende de `numeroTemporada`.

(*entre mas grande el numero de temporadas, el objeto `Serie` quedará ordenado mas al final; entre mas pequeño el numero, el objeto `Serie` quedara mas a la izquierda, en primeras posiciones de una colección*).

Inventemonos algo simple en una clase principal, con una lista y una instancia de un objeto `Serie` que toma dos argumentos (*nombre y numero de temporadas*):

```
series.add( new Serie( "The Simpsons", 29 ) );
series.add( new Serie( "Friends", 10 ) );
series.add( new Serie( "House of Cards", 5 ) );
series.add( new Serie( "Game of Thrones", 7 ) );

for( Serie S : series ) {
  System.out.println( S );// toString() sobre-escrito
}

java.util.Collections.sort( series );// Usa compareTo(Object) para ordenar...

for( Serie S : series ) {
  System.out.println( S );// toString() sobre-escrito
}
```

***Impresion antes de*** `sort()`:

> The Simpsons - 29
>
> Friends - 10
>
> House of Cards - 5
>
> Game of Thrones - 7

***Impresion después de*** `sort()`:

> House of Cards - 5
>
> Game of Thrones - 7
>
> Friends - 10
>
> The Simpsons - 29

Al final se observan ordenados los objetos `Serie` de menor a mayor de acuerdo a su numero de temporadas.

Answer (score 0):

El fragmento de código que presentas es un método llamado `compareTo` (por cierto yo no lo llamaría así, suena demasiado a palabra reservada del lenguage), lo llamaría a lo sumo `myCompareTo`.

Veamos línea por línea:

- `public int compareTo(Object a) {`
  indica que es un método público, que retorna un valor entero y recibe como parámetro un objeto `a`
- `int estado=MENOR;` se crea una variable de tipo `int` y se le asigna el valor de una constante llamada `MENOR` que debe estar declarada en alguna parte del programa.

  -`Serie ref=(Serie)a;` como dice el comentario, se hace un casting del parámetro recibido para que sea un objeto del tipo `Serie`
- `if (numeroTemporadas>ref.getnumeroTemporadas()){` pregunta si la variable `numeroTemporadas` que supongo es un miembro de la clase a la que pertenece tu método, es mayor que el valor que devuelve el método `getnumeroTemporadas()` del objeto que fue recibido en parámetro.
- `estado=MAYOR;` si la condición anterior es verdadera, la variable `estado` tomará el valor de una constante que se llama `MAYOR`
- `}else if(numeroTemporadas==ref.getnumeroTemporadas()){` significa que si no se cumple la condición anterior, evaluará si `numeroTemporadas` es igual al valor devuelto por `getnumeroTemporadas()`, si lo es, la variable estado adquirirá el valor de la constante llamada `IGUAL`.
- `return estado;` le dice que retorne el valor que tenga `estado`, sea el equivalente a `MENOR, MAYOR, IGUAL` según el caso.

Comment: Si quiere comparar objetos entre sí, el nombre usado es el correcto. Pero faltan datos

Comment: @PabloLozano yo entendí que era un método propio .